# Quotient of Fractional Ideals

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, algebraic-geometry, algebraic-number-theory

I am just wondering if the following isomorphism always happens or under some special conditions this holds.
$$ I^{-1}/\mathcal{O}_{K}\cong \mathcal{O}_K/I, $$ where $K$ is a number field, $\mathcal{O}_K$ is ring of integers of $K$ and $I$ is an integral ideal.
Note that those two cardinalities are the same and I believe if K is with class number one then the above isomorphism holds. Thank you for the help.

Comment: have you tried any example without class number one?

Comment: Yes, but it is hard to say because now generators of ideals can be two.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, it is clear as $\mathcal{O}_K$-modules, both are annihilated by $I$, so you may localize both at $S$, the complement of the union of finitely many primes containing $I$. But, then $S^{-1}\mathcal{O}_K$ is a pid and $S^{-1}I$ is principal. Rest should be clear to get your required isomorphism.

Comment: Thank you. Obviously, we know $$S^{-1}\mathcal{O}_K/S^{-1}I\cong\mathcal{O}_K/I$$, but how to deal with $$I^{-1}/\mathcal{O}_K$$?

Comment: $S^{-1}I^{-1}/S^{-1}\mathcal{O}_K=I^{-1}/\mathcal{O}_K$. The terms on the left (after localizing, that is) are isomorphic, since now we are over the pid $S^{-1}\mathcal{O}_K$. So, the right hand sides are isomorphic, which is what we want.